# How do I group similar cells and get the maximum value among those cells?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

```
╔══════╦════════════════════╦══════════╗
║ Name ║        Date        ║  Stage   ║
╠══════╬════════════════════╬══════════╣
║ Dave ║ 4/29/2016 12:15:36 ║ Booking  ║
║ Dave ║ 4/29/2016 17:58:24 ║ Booking  ║
║ Dave ║ 4/29/2016 11:32:59 ║ Costing  ║
║ Dave ║ 4/29/2016 16:52:47 ║ Costing  ║
║ Dave ║ 4/27/2016 16:59:27 ║ Lead     ║
║ Mark ║ 4/22/2016 12:55:22 ║ Booking  ║
║ Mark ║ 4/24/2016 8:00:45  ║ Booking  ║
║ Mark ║ 4/24/2016 10:07:01 ║ Booking  ║
║ Mark ║ 4/24/2016 14:15:30 ║ Booking  ║
║ Mark ║ 4/24/2016 18:55:22 ║ Booking  ║
║ Mark ║ 4/24/2016 21:33:12 ║ Booking  ║
║ Mark ║ 4/20/2016 12:55:22 ║ New      ║
║ Mark ║ 4/23/2016 16:32:22 ║ Planning ║
║ Mark ║ 4/24/2016 9:11:36  ║ Won      ║
║ Mark ║ 4/24/2016 12:55:22 ║ Won      ║
║ Mark ║ 4/24/2016 17:04:02 ║ Won      ║
║ Mark ║ 4/24/2016 19:55:22 ║ Won      ║
║ Mark ║ 4/25/2016 10:19:13 ║ Won      ║
╚══════╩════════════════════╩══════════╝
```

I have the above table on my Google Spreadsheet. What I'm trying to do is group duplicate stages and return the maximum date for each group of stage.

I know how to get the maximum date for all the cells by doing this:
 `=max(arrayformula((B$2:B$19=B2)*(C$2:C$19)))`

But, I'd like to return the maximum date of each stage. I would like my table to look like below:

```
╔══════╦════════════════════╦══════════╦════════════════════╗
║ Name ║        Date        ║  Stage   ║      Max Date      ║
╠══════╬════════════════════╬══════════╬════════════════════╣
║ Dave ║ 4/29/2016 12:15:36 ║ Booking  ║ 4/29/2016 17:58:24 ║
║ Dave ║ 4/29/2016 17:58:24 ║ Booking  ║ 4/29/2016 17:58:24 ║
║ Dave ║ 4/29/2016 11:32:59 ║ Costing  ║ 4/29/2016 16:52:47 ║
║ Dave ║ 4/29/2016 16:52:47 ║ Costing  ║ 4/29/2016 16:52:47 ║
║ Dave ║ 4/27/2016 16:59:27 ║ Lead     ║ 4/27/2016 16:59:27 ║
║ Mark ║ 4/22/2016 12:55:22 ║ Booking  ║ 4/24/2016 21:33:12 ║
║ Mark ║ 4/24/2016 8:00:45  ║ Booking  ║ 4/24/2016 21:33:12 ║
║ Mark ║ 4/24/2016 10:07:01 ║ Booking  ║ 4/24/2016 21:33:12 ║
║ Mark ║ 4/24/2016 14:15:30 ║ Booking  ║ 4/24/2016 21:33:12 ║
║ Mark ║ 4/24/2016 18:55:22 ║ Booking  ║ 4/24/2016 21:33:12 ║
║ Mark ║ 4/24/2016 21:33:12 ║ Booking  ║ 4/24/2016 21:33:12 ║
║ Mark ║ 4/20/2016 12:55:22 ║ New      ║ 4/20/2016 12:55:22 ║
║ Mark ║ 4/23/2016 16:32:22 ║ Planning ║ 4/23/2016 16:32:22 ║
║ Mark ║ 4/24/2016 9:11:36  ║ Won      ║ 4/25/2016 10:19:13 ║
║ Mark ║ 4/24/2016 12:55:22 ║ Won      ║ 4/25/2016 10:19:13 ║
║ Mark ║ 4/24/2016 17:04:02 ║ Won      ║ 4/25/2016 10:19:13 ║
║ Mark ║ 4/24/2016 19:55:22 ║ Won      ║ 4/25/2016 10:19:13 ║
║ Mark ║ 4/25/2016 10:19:13 ║ Won      ║ 4/25/2016 10:19:13 ║
╚══════╩════════════════════╩══════════╩════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Just multiply again by `$A$2:$A$19=A2`

Comment: @RobinGertenbach - Thanks. Can't get this to work. Where would I be adding the formula and how would it know the maximum date from a group of similar stages from a unique name. Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using query. Enter in D2 and copy the formula down:

```
=query($A2:$C19,"select B where A='" & A2 &"' and C='" & C2 &"' order by B desc limit 1 ")
```

Select B gets the dates. Where A = '" & A2 &"' is limiting to the value in cell A2 (the name). C2= is doing the same thing to the cell value in C2. It orders by date. In this case decending order. Limit 1 effectively gets the max date since it only returns one value. I hope that explain the query.

Comment: This works great. **How would I get the minimum value instead of maximum value?** And can you explain in short what's happening in the above query. Would love to learn.

Comment: Sorry for the silly question. Changed `desc` to `asc` and that did the trick. Works fine now. Do let me know what the above query means though.

Comment: This will somehow not work when the Name column is replaced with Numbers (which are same) and the date is set to format Date and time. I get a REF error.

Comment: The date time format should not matter. If I understand you correctly, Dave and Mark are replaced with a single number (like 5). Try formatting the number column as Plain Text and it should work again.